# loop on output and delete in bash

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

Team,
I need to delete 10s of pods on k8s cluster that has error. 
I am getting them as below:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i -e Evict -e Error | awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2, $4}'
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215251 Error
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215252 Error
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215253 Error
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215254 Error
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215255 Error
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215256 Error
```

manually am deleting them like this:

```
kubectl delete pod asdfasdf2215251 -n test-asdfasdf
```

but can I write a script that just looks for error on any pod and deletes all of them? I am working on script myself but new to this hence getting late..

Comment: ubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i -e Evict -e Error | awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2, $4}' | kubectl delete pod $2 -n $1

this does not help.

Comment: ` awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2, $4}'` has no space between `-F ''` and `'{print $1, $2, $4}'`

Comment: kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i -e Evict -e Error | awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2, $4}' | kubectl delete pod $2 -n $1

this does not recognize -n which am using as namespace flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start point:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces |
grep -i -e Evict -e Error |
awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2}' |
```

will produce a stream of:

```
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215251
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215252
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215253
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215254
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215255
test-asdfasdf asdfasdf2215256
```

we can go here:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r arg1 arg2; do
    kubectl delete pod "$arg2" -n "$arg1"
done
```

we can go here:

```
xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl delete pod "$2" -n "$1"' --
```

or use `parallel` or any kind of other tools to do that.

Comment: aah.. that worked.

(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i -e Evict -e Error | awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2, $4}' | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl delete pod "$2" -n "$1"' --)